# Find a differential equations using linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $V$ is vector space that have function in this form

$\alpha e^{2x} \cos x +\beta e^{2x} \sin x$

where $\alpha , \beta \in \mathbb R$, and linear transformation $L:V\to V$ is going like this:

$L(f)=f´+f$

a)Find a matrix of linear operator using a base

${e^{2x} \cos x,e^{2x} \sin x}$

b) using that solution find a solution for differential equation $y´+y=e^{2x}$

I know for a) it is easy since $L(e^{2x} \cos x)=3e^{2x}\cos x-e^{2x}\sin x$,  $L(e^{2x}\sin x)=e^{2x}\cos x+e^{2x}\sin x$

so matrix is

L=$\begin{bmatrix}
      3& -1\\
      1& 3
     \end{bmatrix}$

for b) I know $f(y)=y´+y=e^{2x}\cos x$, since $y\in V$ then $y=\alpha e^{2x}\cos x+\beta e^{2x}\sin x$,

so $f(\alpha e^{2x}\cos x+\beta e^{2x}\sin x)=e^{2x}\cos x$, now $\alpha f(e^{2x}\cos x)+\beta f( e^{2x}\sin x)=e^{2x}\cos x$,

and I get $\cos x(3\alpha+\beta)+\sin x(3\beta-\alpha)=\cos x$,

but know I know that if I find a solution for$ \alpha$ and $\beta$ I get $y_p=\frac{1}{10}e^{2x}\sin x+\frac{3}{10}e^{2x}\cos x$,

but I do not know how to get homogeneous solution, I know that I need to get $y_h=Ce^{-x}$,

but I have no idea how to get solution I know that I use matrix and find eigenvalues, and eigenvectors for system, and I get $\lambda_1=3+i$ and $\lambda2=3-i$, but somehow I need to get a $\lambda=-1$ but how to get that?, can someone help me please, again sorry i need to change since I can not ask more than 50 question

Comment: So the rank of $A^2$ is less than rank of $A$ and there is nothing strange here. In general of course we know that the nul space of $A $ is in the nul space of $A^2$.

Comment: What you are saying is that if $A $ is singular (has zero eigenvalue), then $A^2$ is also singular. This is true.

Comment: I said that here all eigenvalue is zero, but $rankaA>0$, how is possible that eigenvalue does not show that $rankA>0$, because almost always they show if some eigenvalue is not zero so $rankA>0$

Comment: $rank A=rank AA^T$ , while $rank A\leq rank A^2$, because $rank AB \leq \min(rank A, rank B)$

Comment: You’ve discovered that having no non-zero eigenvalues is not a sufficient condition for the rank of the matrix to be zero. In fact, all nilpotent matrices have only zero for an eigenvalue, but most of them have rank greater than zero.

Comment: So all nilpotent matrices have zero as the only eigenvalue, as you suggest (since some power of the nilpotent matrix is zero). And as one knows nilpotent matrix is not necessarilt a zero matrix as pointed out by @amd.

Comment: BTW. Try to type sine and cosine as `\sin` and `\cos` in math. The difference is $\sin x$ vs $sinx$. It is much easier to read as it groups the function name together with upright characters, as opposed to italicised variables.